# Аутенфикация Laravel+AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, laravel

Всем привет.
Пытаюсь сделать аутенфикацию на angular+laravel

Код Angular

```
var Memoris = angular.module('Memoris', ['ngRoute']);

function Auth($scope,$http, $location){
    $scope.authenfication = function(){
        $http({
            url: "/auth",
            method: "POST",
            data: {login: $scope.login, password: $scope.password}
        }).success(function(isAuth) {
            if (isAuth) {
                $location.path('/admin/uss');
            }
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.status = status;
        });
    }
}

Memoris.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/admin/auth', {
            templateUrl : 'view/auth.html'
        })
        .when('/admin/uss', {
            templateUrl : 'view/isAuthTrue.html'
        });

    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); });


Memoris.controller('Auth', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', Auth]);
```

В laravel использую ручную аутенфикацию

```
public function postIndex()
{

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => Request::input('login'), 'password' => Request::input('password')])) {
        return Auth::user();
    }
}
```

Условие выполняется, но сессия не создается. Поля с куками пустые.
Делаю обычный способ авторизации без angular - все хорошо.
В чем может быть проблема? Бьюсь уже второй день

laravel 5.2